# Export Qgis settings

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Is there a way to export my customized settings or copy some xml or config file, in order to install my settings to another computer without me manually changing everything? If this is possible it would make the installation process much easier for people who are not that familier with GIS.

Many people at my workplace are going to be using Qgis in the future and this would make the transition easier :)

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: see [Can I transfer custom QGIS settings from one computer to another?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57540/can-i-transfer-custom-qgis-settings-from-one-computer-to-another/57574#57574)